# What type of cache misses occur when accessing consecutive elements of array?

Tags: c, caching

In C, f you have this type of loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
  sum += a[i]
```

where the array 'a' contains ints (4 bytes) and a cache block can store say, 32 bytes, then I know that there will be a cold miss every 8 iterations of the loop, since the processor will load 8 ints into a block, then not get a cache miss until the 9th iteration. Am I understanding that correctly, that when it gets a cache miss at a[0] it loads a[0]-a[7] into a cache block, and won't load any of 'a' into cache again until it gets another cold miss at a[8]?

Assuming that ^^ is correct, my real question is, what happens if you have  something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      a[i] = a[i+1]
```

where 'a' has not been initialized? Would you get something similar to above, where the processor looks for each consecutive value of a[i+1] and misses only every 8? Or does it search the cache for a[i] as well in order to set the value? Would there be cache misses associated with a[i] or just a[i+1]?

And finally, what would happen if you had

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
      b[i] = a[i]
```

Would this be analogous to the first example, where it looks for each value of a[i] and gets cache misses on every 8th iteration, or does setting the value of b[i] incur cache misses as well?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "cold miss"?

Comment: Without a specific architecture in mind, this question is too broad to answer.

Comment: @Chipster "cold miss" as in a cache miss that occurs because the item has never been loaded into the cache before. As opposed to a capacity miss, where you're working with a data set that is bigger than the capacity of the cache, or a conflict miss, where two items that you keep trying to access get saved to the same place in the cache, so they keep conflicting with each other.

Comment: @GovindParmar 64-bit computer, single cache, direct-mapped, write-through, write-allocate, cache blocks are 4 words each, and he cache has 256 sets.

Comment: @gkeenley So, are you asking does the data get lost, or are you asking about efficiency?

Comment: There's no reason to assume that the array is aligned with the beginning of a cache line.

Comment: In your question, apart from using strange language ("cold miss"?) you are making big assumptions, such as your program/thread having exclusive access to the processor/core and its cache.   In the real world, what happens depends on the processor design, memory hierarchy (how many levels of cache, different types of memory and hardware devices), how the compiler optimises code, and a bunch of things.   The reasoning is statistical as well - for a given sequence of instructions, there are certain chances of being preempted, processor stalls, etc which all affect what is left in cache.

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the asm code, you should read it and see whether your program read a[i] first or a[i+1] first.